# Is Struts 1 supported by Tomcat 8.0.9?

Tags: tomcat, struts-1

Is Struts 1 supported by Tomcat 8.0.9? Its is working on my local development environment which is having tomcat 7.x but not working on server which has 8.0.9 version.

I am having this doubt because of this.

`http://localhost:8080/AppName/login.do`

I have a login form. When i click on submit button the URL is like this:  But when application is deployed on server after submitting the form the URL comes as

`http://DomainName/AppName/?user=&emailaddress=&submitbutton=#`

Please help me to find out the issue.

Comment: Can you please tell what problem are you facing? Are you getting any error? Any stack trace ?

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to write `action` attribute in your form tag.

`<form action="YOUR_ACTION_SHOULD_COME_HERE" method="post">`

Comment: I have written that. It is working on my local machine. But not on server.  <html:form styleId="myForm" action="loginAction.do">

Comment: @user3812157 What error are you getting? Anything in server's log?

Comment: No error in server logs. And one more thing.  In case of simple hello world application if i call the URL http://domain/AppName/welcome.do  which just forwards request to a simple jsp page, is not working. It says AppName/welcome.do not found. Whereas it is working on my machine.

Comment: @user3812157 I hope you are not statically mentioning the domain name there. Only relative path should be given.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is only about *"Is Struts 1 supported by Tomcat 8.0.9"*, the easiest way for you to check it out is to install Tomcat 8.0.9 in your local development machine and see, as you already said it is working in your local dev machine with Tomcat version 7.x. Personally I don't see a reason why a servlet container is dependent on the Struts version

If you still have issue, then the case is different, and probably with the pathname configuration.

For the below URL to show up, you must configure it somewhere, and that configuration is wrong. can you share what you did for that

```
http://DomainName/AppName/?user=&emailaddress=&submitbutton=#
```